# Are there kanji which are NOT words by themselves (written standalone)?

Tags: words, kanji, compounds, okurigana

In other words, are there kanji, which can **only** be used as a part of a kanji compound and/or with okurigana?

For example:

1. **見 - standalone kanji**, a word which means "view", "outlook"
2. 見物 - kanji compound: "sightseeing", "watching", etc.
3. 見る - kanji + okurigana: "to see", "to look", etc.

Is there a kanji where (1) is not an option?

If there are such kanji, do they have some special name?

Comment: I was looking for a designation of these jukugo-only / non-word / non-standalone kanji. But saying that 非単漢字 is not a common designation is probably an understatement given I can't even find 非単 in JDIC :D At any rate, is there a formal name given by western linguist to these kanjis? I recall having read in a page about Chinese that such characters are "bound" morphemes that need at least another character to get their meaning in opposition to "free" morphemes that can stand by themselves.

Comment: Please ask questions only via the "[Ask Question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" button. (You've posted your question as an answer to a different if related question.) You may want to link to this question in your new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are, but it is a grey area if you include rare, uncommon, creative or archaic readings.

People can be creative especially when it comes to *kun*-readings. Even for a *kanji* usually used only in compounds you might find a stand-alone usage if you're looking hard enough. Some of these need *okurigana*, eg. 隷う【したがう】 or 悠か【はるか】, but some don't, eg. 英【はやぶさ】.

Additionally, there are some *on* readings that are rarely used as a word, eg. 感 or 奏 or 了, although it could be argued sometimes only as part of some (more or less) fixed expressions. The same applies to 見 as well, 見【けん】 is not a common "word", but you can find it in expressions such as:

> それは皮相【ひそう】の見【けん】である
>
> That's a rather superficial view of things.

A Japanese name could be [非単漢字](http://kindaigo.org/youshi00.html), but that's more like a description, *and not exactly common*.

If you're looking for a technical term, it is called `word`. I know it sounds simple, but effectively you are asking whether there is a *kanji* that cannot be used as a word by itself without further glyphs (*kanji* or *kana*).

> A word is a unit which is a constituent at the phrase level and above. It is sometimes identifiable according to such criteria as
>
> - being the minimal possible unit in a reply
> - having features such as
> - a regular stress pattern, and
> - phonological changes conditioned by or blocked at word boundaries
> - being the largest unit resistant to insertion of new constituents within its boundaries, or
> - being the smallest constituent that can be moved within a sentence without making the sentence ungrammatical.
>
> A word is sometimes placed, in a hierarchy of grammatical constituents, above the morpheme level and below the phrase level.
>   source: [SIL Linguistics](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAWord.htm)

見【けん】 is not a word as in that you can just say or answer 見【けん】です ("it is a view") and expect people to understand.

Some *kanji* I can think of, mostly used only in one compound, with no *kun*-readings by themselves:

> 蝙蝠 (bat, the animal), 蟷螂 (mantis), 髑髏 (skull), 躊躇 (hesitate)

But rarely: 蝠【まむし】, 躇む【ふむ】, 躊う【ためらう】

Some more *kanji* if we don't count *okurigana*:

> 乖 (eg. 乖離), 擁 (eg. 抱擁), 倣 (eg. 模倣), 避 (eg. 回避), 喚 (eg. 叫喚)

Comment: I was looking for a designation of these jukugo-only / non-word / non-standalone kanji. But saying that 非単漢字 is not a common designation is probably an understatement given I can't even find 非単 in JDIC :D At any rate, is there a formal name given by western linguist to these kanjis? I recall having read in a page about Chinese that such characters are "bound" morphemes that need at least another character to get their meaning in opposition to "free" morphemes that can stand by themselves.

Comment: Please ask questions only via the "[Ask Question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" button. (You've posted your question as an answer to a different if related question.) You may want to link to this question in your new question.